# Java application closes after some time on Fedora

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fedora

I currently have the following problem:

I have created a Java (FX) Application which runs on Fedora. When I start it, it first runs the cache builder. This loads 40 MB into the memory. Then it just shows a screen and in a background thread it keeps the cache up to date.

The problem is that the application closes after 1.5h of inactivity of the user. I first thought of a memory issue, so I did some research.

If I do not use the application for something else, the CPU and memory usage is as follows:
[image: CPU and memory usage]

As you can see, the `Garbage Collection` is called by the application, and the memory is freed. It stays at a level of 40 MB, which is perfect.

**So if memory is not the issue, what else could it be?**

I can not find an error log of the JVM anywhere, so it doesn't look like the JVM is crashing. I am using Java 8u25.

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about some uncaught exception?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Malt. I do not get that on Mac. The application is now running for more than 2 hours on Mac OSX, still no problem at all!

Comment: The fact that there aren't any problems yet doesn't mean anything. Are you logging your exceptions? Does your program have a System.exit() call someplace?

Comment: I am logging my errors but I do not see one, so it could be uncaught. I have no System.exit() call, I close my application with stage.close().

Comment: Well, make sure you're not reaching that `exit` by mistake somehow.

Comment: I did not touch the computer when testing it, and it still closed the application.. My code does not call that button for certain.

Comment: Well, the fact that the application closed doesn't mean that it closed just because some time has passed. It could be that something that your code did internally threw an exception or finished the program.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why it is not happening on Mac OSX, or is this a wrong assumption?